Is mind-body dualism falsifiable?
I've previously asked Is epiphenomenalism falsifiable?, which was well-received, so I’d like to explore a follow-up. Are there any versions of mind-body dualism that make testable predictions, thus being empirically falsifiable? It seems this would likely require a detailed hypothesis on how the mind causally interacts with the physical realm and vice versa—a concept that could, in principle, be tested with experiments. However, if such tests were successful, and the hypothesis achieved the status of a theory, what would stop us from simply considering the mind as another aspect of physical reality, ultimately subsuming everything under the domain of physics? In that case, dualism would no longer hold, as there would be only one unified realm containing what used to be labeled as physics + the new laws governing minds and their interactions with matter, energy, fields, spacetime, etc.
In short, I have two questions:

Are there versions of mind-body dualism that are empirically testable?
Even if such versions existed and passed empirical tests, what would prevent us from eventually reclassifying everything as part of physics, thereby dissolving the dualism?


Definitions of mind-body dualism (from different sources)
From Britannica:

Mind-body dualism, in its original and most radical formulation, the philosophical view that mind and body (or matter) are fundamentally distinct kinds of substances or natures. That version, now often called substance dualism, implies that mind and body not only differ in meaning but refer to different kinds of entities. Thus, a mind-body (substance) dualist would oppose any theory that identifies mind with the brain, conceived as a physical mechanism.

From Wikipedia:

In the philosophy of mind, mind–body dualism denotes either the view that mental phenomena are non-physical, or that the mind and body are distinct and separable. Thus, it encompasses a set of views about the relationship between mind and matter, as well as between subject and object, and is contrasted with other positions, such as physicalism and enactivism, in the mind–body problem.
[...]
Dualism is closely associated with the thought of René Descartes (1641), who holds that the mind is a nonphysical—and therefore, non-spatial—substance. Descartes clearly identified the mind with consciousness and self-awareness and distinguished this from the physical brain as the seat of intelligence. Hence, he was the first documented Western philosopher to formulate the mind–body problem in the form in which it exists today. However, the theory of substance dualism has many advocates in contemporary philosophy such as Richard Swinburne, William Hasker, J. P. Moreland, E. J. Low, Charles Taliaferro, Seyyed Jaaber Mousavirad, and John Foster.
Dualism is contrasted with various kinds of monism. Substance dualism is contrasted with all forms of materialism, but property dualism may be considered a form of non-reductive physicalism.

From IEP, Dualism and Mind:

Dualism and Mind
Dualists in the philosophy of mind emphasize the radical difference between mind and matter. They all deny that the mind is the same as the brain, and some deny that the mind is wholly a product of the brain. This article explores the various ways that dualists attempt to explain this radical difference between the mental and the physical world. A wide range of arguments for and against the various dualistic options are discussed.
Substance dualists typically argue that the mind and the body are composed of different substances and that the mind is a thinking thing that lacks the usual attributes of physical objects: size, shape, location, solidity, motion, adherence to the laws of physics, and so on. Substance dualists fall into several camps depending upon how they think mind and body are related. Interactionists believe that minds and bodies causally affect one another. Occasionalists and parallelists, generally motivated by a concern to preserve the integrity of physical science, deny this, ultimately attributing all apparent interaction to God. Epiphenomenalists offer a compromise theory, asserting that bodily events can have mental events as effects while denying that the reverse is true, avoiding any threat to the scientific law of conservation of energy at the expense of the common sense notion that we act for reasons.
Property dualists argue that mental states are irreducible attributes of brain states. For the property dualist, mental phenomena are non-physical properties of physical substances. Consciousness is perhaps the most widely recognized example of a non-physical property of physical substances. Still other dualists argue that mental states, dispositions and episodes are brain states, although the states cannot be conceptualized in exactly the same way without loss of meaning.
Dualists commonly argue for the distinction of mind and matter by employing Leibniz’s Law of Identity, according to which two things are identical if, and only if, they simultaneously share exactly the same qualities. The dualist then attempts to identify attributes of mind that are lacked by matter (such as privacy or intentionality) or vice versa (such as having a certain temperature or electrical charge). Opponents typically argue that dualism is (a) inconsistent with known laws or truths of science (such as the aforementioned law of thermodynamics), (b) conceptually incoherent (because immaterial minds could not be individuated or because mind-body interaction is not humanly conceivable), or (c) reducible to absurdity (because it leads to solipsism, the epistemological belief that one’s self is the only existence that can be verified and known).


Please, first state your definition of mind-body dualism. Thanks.

@JoWehler Edited.

What results would an answer have, beyond settling this question?

@ScottRowe I depends on the answer. If the answer is "yes", well, you could scientifically test mind-body dualism (and possibly win a Nobel Prize). If the answer is "no", then mind-body dualism would be unfalsifiable, which would mean we are left with a mystery, with no clear path to settle it beyond endless debates.

No. There's no answer. Is there a prove about creating of the nothing; this is a widsom hypothesis only. It is being to more easy that we understanding the material. The difference spiriualism and body-mind dualism is existence of auto/self-control mechanism.

There is no point replicating "is X falsifiable?" with various established philosophical doctrines for X. The answer is always no and for the same reason. Philosophical doctrines are not meant to be testable, they are meant to generate and organize approaches to problems and ways of thinking about a subject. They may suggest or inspire certain types of testable theories in this or that context, and thereby prove fruitful or otherwise. But they are too far removed from predictions and have too much flexibility to accommodate the outcomes to be either confirmed or disconfirmed by them.

Your first question is essentially similar to the other one on the falsifiability of epiphenomenalism, and my answer to that one applies here: e.g. one could falsify mind-body dualism by giving an account of history with no recourse to ideologies as a force. That would be a purely materialistic history, a history of bodies, and not of minds, or one where minds would entirely depend / derive from bodies. It may seem impossible, but it is theoretically doable -- in fact Karl Marx gave it a try -- and hence it ticks the falsifiability box.
How would it falsify mind-body dualism? History is currently understood, at least by dualists (following Collingwood and contra Marx), as essentially about the history of thought, because it's always a narrative based mainly on previous narratives. By showing that history (ie social events) can be causaly understood within a frame where mental events play no role at all, a materialistic history would undermine belief in the causal power of mental events.
More broadly, the idea is to challenge the view that social events are built upon a foundation of mental events, that human society is essentially inter-subjective, to challenge the idea that there could be no human society worth of the name without a common culture, or at least without an intellectual exchange, a dialogue and some attempt at resolving disputes through law.
You need to prove wrong the idea that human society is premissed on the causal mental events of individual folks, such as ideas, values, fashions, desires and interests. That's my challenge for epiphenomenalists.
I find your second question more challenging. Once we uncover the mystery of the mind, we could indeed decide to call it "physical". Incidentally, that's why I personally don't use the term "physical": it means very little nowadays. Anything and everything is "physical", even probabilities.
But you go one step further than just classify the mind as physical:

what would prevent us from eventually reclassifying everything as part of physics, thereby dissolving the dualism?

And yet, modern physics are characterized by the wave-particle duality, which is NOT dissolved in any way. Rather, this duality is deemed fundamental to our physical reality. Now, it could very well be that, once we understand the mystery of the mind, we are faced with a similar fundamental duality. If this is the case, we could explain the mind "physically" yet still remain dualists.

Frankly, l don't understand how giving an acount of history with no recourse to ideologies as a force could falsify mind-body dualism. FWIW, did not downvote your answer.

Though the idea sounds similar to  Alex Rosenberg's 'How history gets things wrong '. But I think he was an eliminative materialist.  Hardly an ally for the dualist program..

@Philomath A way to falsify dualism is what the OP asked for, and I tried to provide an idea to that end. Evidently, to falsify dualism cannot be "an ally for dualists", so that's to be expected.

"but do remember that as per this site's rules, members are encouraged to provide detailed comments rather than just lazingly downvote what they don't agree with."  That is not true at all.  Theres no requirement to explain or justify downvotes. Quite frankly, I'm not even sure what you mean referring to site rules that encourage you to comment.  Being encouraged to do something isnt even a rule at all, it's a suggestion. https://philosophy.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/485/should-we-explain-downvotes

@JMac That sounds like a meta question, so it may be more appropriate to discuss that on the meta site, but it's my understanding that instead of or in addition to voting down, posters are encouraged to comment, edit or flag content which they find inaccurate.

@Olivier5 "Encouraged" is far from a rule, and even then the wording is typically along the lines of "leave a comment if you think the post can be improved", which isn't the same as leaving a comment for any down voting.  And yes, it is a meta discussion, so you probably dont need to leave an (incorrect) comment about peoples voting habits in the answer.  The CoC specifically guides you to vote down answers you think are bad, and use comments when you have constructive criticism.

@JMac I believe my statement about the CoC is factually correct, but I'm happy to delete it if it distracts from the answer. I got my message across anyway.

I don't think so. As it says in the Wikipedia page, this dualism includes

the view that mental phenomena are non-physical

When we perform experiments or make empirical observations, we're only able to observe physical results. If mental phenomena are non-physical, we can't observe them in order to draw conclusions.

I would argue the opposite. Human observers recognize mental events and then we generate conceptual knowledge of physical models derived from mental experience.

That sounds like solipsism -- the physical world doesn't necessarily exist, all we have is the mental world.

But in that case the concept of dualism doesn't make sense, since there's no physical dual.

The physical world apparently exists independent of the mind but we only form mental models derived from qualia, desire, and conceptual knowledge arising in the mind.

What about the physical measuring devices that we use to make observations? That's the point of my answer. And our physical sensory organs? These are all involved before we make mental models.

Measuring instruments are physical devices built to perform measurement functions only in accord with our conceptual knowledge. Instruments must be designed and calibrated to specify physical quantities in accord with our concepts of standard units of measure, accuracy, and precision. Otherwise, the physical device is not performing the function that we recognize as scientific observation. Sensory organs do function in accord with conceptual knowledge of physical models. But animals and human children experience qualia and desire. Conceptual knowledge makes sense of qualia arising in the mind.

I would argue that if mental phenomena can be proven "unobservable" (in essence i.e. qualia, and not due to limitations of human experimental skills), then that itself validates the mind-body duality. So, this doesn't answer the question. The answer about whether it is falsifiable is therefore centered around if the theory "mental phenomena are unobservable in essence" is falsifiable

@RabbiKaii But how do you prove it "unobservable" without doing an experiment whose results show that? This reeks of the "proving a negative" problem.

@Barmar so therefore, it's not falsifiable. One can only hope to try and prove the null hypothesis and prove that it is observable to falsify it. The Knowledge Argument is not resolved as of yet. Many people feel it in their gut that qualia are unobservable, and that is significant, but because it is unprovable, there are many who argue, and it does mark a decided difference of opinion between these groups

@RabbiKaii What does it mean "qualia are unobservable?" When my nephew is two years old he points to a painting with a sailboat, sea, and clouds, and says, "Gauggy", which is his effort to say, "Doggy". I cannot observe the qualia in his mind when decoding the meaning of his sentence but I can observe or note the qualia in my own mind. So qualia are subjectively observable but do you mean no physical device could detect the presence or absence of qualia let alone map language or symbols to the specific content arising in any isolated subjective mind?

@SystemTheory yes that's basically it. Someone with monochromatism could never observe red, regardless of our technology (beyond fixing their eyes/brain, but that doesn't give us any qualia information, basically qualia are a type of information we have no idea how to define or capture within the tools we have available in the physical/materialisic paradigm) For more information, see https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/qualia-knowledge/

Basically both those who say qualia are of course observable, we just haven't figured out how, and the people who strongly feel that qualia are inherently unobservable, are both sitting in the unfalsifiable bin, until some progress is made towards capturing qualia with our tools, such as explaining what are the made from/caused by, what's the logic of their composition, or is there some way to define them using logic or formal mathematics/equations? It's possible that the act of "capturing them" itself will falsify the theory that they are unobservable, but no progress has been made there.

@RabbiKaii Whenever I have closed-captioning turned on, I wonder how deaf people understand descriptions like "tire squeals" or "a door creaks". I supposed that after a lifetime of living among hearing people they've formed some concepts of the sonic world from these indirect references, despite not experiencing it directly. Maybe those concepts are analogous to qualia....

@Barmar a perfect example

Of course interactive dualism is testable, and falsifiable.    It is an interactive model, so one can do studies on whether brain or body affect mind, and if so how, and whether mind affects brain or body, and if so how. In both cases, the test data would include both first person reports, and externally collected data about body and brain.
Note, "falsifiable" is explicitly not true -- Quine refuted falsifiability, but one can take it as an aspirational method, which forces a theory to adapt to challenging data even if a theory is not falsified.
Two of the test suites that have been done that provide a positive set of results are tests that see if the homunculus model of a mind controlling a brain actually fits the data of consciousness or not.  Dualism has been ridiculed for its "homunculus" model.  But very interestingly, both the System 2 of Thinking Fast and Slow, and the somewhat mislead and pandered to chief executive of Incognito are both "homunculi" models.  The best of modern decision lab tests, and neuroscience on unconscious/conscious communication both point to the dualist model of a conscious mind steering an unconscious brain (as well as the unconscious brain misleading the conscious mind!).
However, another book compiles an even larger suite of challenging test cases. Per the main spiritual dualist models, of a mind being spiritual, therefore our reasoning and personality only going "offline" when the brain shuts down, we have instead a collection of test cases where personality (and system 2 reasoning) is strongly influenced by:

Mechanical injury to the brain (Phineas Gage, surgery, alzheimers)
Chemical influence on the brain (drugs, both good and bad)
Fatigue, illness, dehydration, etc.

These effects on one's ability to think and so to steer one's brain, are documented by multiple contributing authors in Section One of The Myth of an Afterlife.  It is a very effective collection of test cases that show that the most common spiritual dualist models (TV broadcast station, drone operator, and filter theory) are not adequate to explain the interaction of body back onto mind.   Here is my review.  https://www.amazon.com/gp/customer-reviews/R10Z02T2ZEYPFY/ref=cm_cr_dp_d_rvw_ttl?ie=UTF8&ASIN=0810886774
Emergent interactive dualist models, like those of Popper and Bradley are not refuted by this test data on the brain affecting the mind.  In my review, I also note that the spiritual interactive models can be tweaked to fit the data, by assuming a partial offload on mind processing to neurology by a spiritual mind (the non-zero intercept on processing capability as less brain is available, noted in the review).  Augustine's goal was to rebut spiritual dualism, and he was fine with an emergent dualist model being part of his anti-afterlife argument.  But his presumption that spiritual processing being dependent meant a zero intercept was untrue, and his presumption of no repurposing of spiritual thruput upon death could also be untrue, so his "refutation" had holes in it.
While emergent dualism does better on brain damage affecting personality, the parapsych data cited in section 4 of Myth of an Afterlife is challenging data for emergent dualism, and strongly supports spiritual dualism instead.

I think this answer might be improved by making explicit the difference in falsifiability (or impossibility thereof) between claims about what reality is (the various -isms) and claims about what reality does under certain circumstances (the various -ist models). I can make my own answer if you don't feel like editing.

Unless my unconscious brain is misleading my conscious mind,  doesn't the homunculus lead to infinite regress?

It might also be worth mentioning that "mind" does NOT mean "brain". Mind is the concept for the thing that conceives of concepts, something like the conscious self, while the brain is the physical substance where we most likely suppose to find that, but whether that intuition is indeed correct is not completely certain otherwise such questions wouldn't be asked.

@Philomath Dualism is a hypothesis: there is a conscious agent steering an unconscious brain.  Nothing in this hypothesis is based on a logical necessity claim that a thing that acts needs another thing steering it.  It is just a model, a hypothesis, that can be tested.  No, there is no infinite logical regression.

@Dcleve If the conscious agent is to steer an unconscious brain it needs a physical component to interact with the physical brain. This means that you have to invoke another conscious agent to steer the physical component in the first conscious agent. Ad infinitum. Otherwise you are left with the mystery of a conscious mind to steer an unconscious brain. This would mean giving up physical closure and leaving the door open to all sorts of witchcraft.

@Philomath  Assuming causal closure of the physical does not lead to dualist logical recursion, it instead prohibits interactive dualism full stop.  Arguing for closure by namecalling and wish-it-were-so are fallacies.  If you want to claim causal closure of the physical is a necessary assumption for the world, you need to provide the derivation.  An empirically counter: a) causal closure is impossible for any science, as sciences are open subjects, with indeterminate extent.  b) Physics is indeterminate, hence cannot be closed. c) science cannot justify itself, so science cannot be closed.

@Dcleve This is no namecalling. Giving up causal closure means that anything can happen without demonstrable cause. This is magic. Arguing for closure is just as little a wish-it-were-so fallacy as arguing for a finite speed of light.Your empirical encounter seem to rest on an appeal to quantum indeterminancy. But quantum indeterminancy in no way suggests that the universe is not causally closed. Causal closure just asserts that all causes of physical events are themselves entirely physical. I don't understand c.

@Philomath that "anything can happen" is just what science assumes -- our universe is contingent, and we investigate it, to figure out if what happens has regularities.  "Causal closure" is a different claim than "'assume causation", and cosmologists do not assume it.  Neither do theoretical physicists, who continually postulate new causations outside known physics. Indeterminacy means multiple outcomes are consistent with physics, and which one we get is not dependent on our physics -- IE our universe is not causally closed. You may wish it, but theory and practice do not support your wish.

Give me one example of a theoretical physicist who postulates an non-physical cause for a phenomenon. Since they are continually postulating new causations outside known physics, this shouldn't be too difficult. Indeterminancy does not violate causal closure. It simply means that we do not know what it is, but we are sure it is a physical cause. More in general, your claim that the universe is contingent is still an open question. I am not too well versed in Aristotelian or scholastic philosophy, but I lean more towards Superdeterminism or a Many Worlds interpretation.

@Philomath  Max Tegmark, who postulates that math simply creates matter.  Roger Penrose, who is a version of a Popperian 3 world triplest.  Carl Sagan, who was a fierce defender of parapsych as a science field.  But you misunderstood the sentence.  PHYSICS CANNOT BE CLOSED, because it is an active science.  Physicists cannot treat physics as closed.  2nd sentence -- if physics is indeterminate, then it cannot cause a specific outcome.  MWI does not change that -- our particular observation is still not determinate -- MWI fails test cases without the Born rule, which is a probabilistic add on.

@Dcleve I don't think Max Tegmark postulates that matter creates matter. He postulates that there is a mathematical structure that is isomorphic to our physical world. Wikipedia describes it as the universe is mathematics. This sounds like some type identity theory to me. Either way, I sincerely doubt Tegmark would discard causal closure. Carl Sagan has given three examples of parapsychological phenomena that he thought deserved scientific scrutiny. He too said he didn't think they would hold up. To try to base these phenomena in science is not what you think it is: giving magic a free pass.

Newton dabbled in astrology. Just shows. Penrose had his own metaphysical theory. Doesn't mean he discards causal closure. I read some of his CCC. Interesting stuff. Repeating your claim in capital letters doesn't make it true. I think you misunderstand the fact that physics isn't complete. I still don't understand where you get this idea that physicists cannot treat physics as causally closed. As far as I know, most do. And I already explained that quantum indeterminancy doesn't mean a physical event is caused by a non-physical event.

@Philomath Tegmark thinks that all coherent math creates a universe that actualizes it.  The causation runs one way -- from abstraction (world 3) to matter (world 1).  World 1 is not causally closed in his thinking.  Interactive triplism also necessitates that world 1 is not causally closed.  It does not matter how many or few parapsychic processes Sagan supported doing science on, parapsychologists are not physicalist, because their phenomena break physical causal closure. You asked for one physicist.  I gave you three. Why did you ask, if all you will do is raise the bar and special plead?

@Dcleve I apologise if you think I argue in bad faith. I assure you that is not the case.You complain about me raising the bar, but you move the goalposts by now defining physics as pertaining to the highly speculative physics of the purely hypothetical multiverse of Tegmark's Level I universes and far beyond. Even then Tegmark writes: p15: Level I, II and III parallel universes are all part of the same mathematical structure, but from the frog perspective, they are for all practical purposes causally disconnected. This is from his 2007 paper, The Mathematical Universe.

@Dcleve The paper is very interesting and I have to thank you for drawing my attention to it. It is surprisingly insightful. However, I see no reason to assume that Tegmark has abandoned causal closure. If you want I can give you more arguments why I think that. The 'triplism' described by Penrose in his book Road to Reality shows a striking resemblance with Popper's. However, closer scrutiny (chapter 1.4) shows that the arrows only go in one direction. Reading the text, it is clear that Penrose does not think the Platonic world actually has causal effect on the physical world.

@Dcleve Penrose: The mathematical forms of Plato’s world clearly do not have the same kind of existence as do ordinary physical objects such as tables and chairs. They do not have spatial locations; nor do they exist in time. It is clear that if they do not exist in time, they can not have causal effect. The book is very interesting (>1100 pages) and I will definitely read it! Thanks.

@Philomath -- The summaries I have read of Tegmark have him asserting that every different math causes different universes, a math theory version of an infinite multiverse.  Tegmark is not the only physicist who has gone reductive of matter to math.  The Hologrammatic Universe models, plus anyone saying "shut up and calculate" are treating math as more fundamental than matter, and are extending reductionism to an abstract object limit case.

If Penrose holds that abstract objects are a-causal, then we could then have no knowledge of them.  Popper is a far better philosopher, and his Tanner Lecture is a more useful reference on what triplism has to do:  https://tannerlectures.org/lectures/three-worlds/  Meanwhile, physics today has basically accepted that one must specify both objects and information to do physics, it is a "dualist" field.  That information is needed to DO physics strongly implies that worlds 1 and 3 are interactive, contrary to Popper, Frege, and Penrose.  Triplism needs 6 sets of interaction laws.

Well, if you want to hold on to Tegmark as an example of theoretical physician who doesn't believe in causal closure, then I guess I have to concede that you found one. I guess it was infelicitous of me to think that would work. If I had asked you to name one biologist who believes in Young Earth Creationism, I am sure you could have found me one too. Anyone saying "shut op and calculate" and finds an outcome that doesn't agree with physical experiment, you think they will say: "no matter, mathematics trumps physics" or "we have to readjust our calculations"?

You will not be surprised that I totally disagree with your second lemma. Music can move me to tears, but I think that is entirely explicable in terms of human phyisology. I don't think for a moment that there is a Platonic entity that has a causal effect on my physiology. I don't understand what you mean with "information is needed to DO physics"? With doing physics I understand physics as a sience not physics itself. Physics works in the universe independent of any human observers or interaction.

@Philomath  Well, the rationale for why Sean Carroll thinks the infinity of universes of the MW interpretation actually exist is because "they are there in the math", and the rationale for Leonard Susskind to reject Popperian falsificationism as a criterial for the reality of the multiverse is because "the math is consistent".  Your faith in empiricism trumping abstract theory among all other theoretical physicists aside from Tegmark -- is misplaced.  As for science method -- if the model with matter and information interacting makes valid predictions then science thinks the world does too.

Not sure this is the argument you want. The Many Worlds interpretation assumes the universal wave function is real and evolves entirely deterministically (and locally). This makes an even stronger case for causal closure. This is as hard deterministic as it gets. Note that this is also true for Tegmark's Mathematical Universe: it is an entirely deterministic block universe. As for Susskind: Of course the math is consistent, but the reason why Susskind would think he can dismiss falsificationism is undoubtedly the measure problem which is the whole rationale for the MW interpretation.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

Yes, mind-body dualism is empirically testable.
According to this article by Harold J. Morowitz

Cartesian mind body dualism and modern versions of this viewpoint posit a mind thermodynamically unrelated to the body but informationally interactive. The relation between information and entropy developed by Leon Brillouin demonstrates that any information about the state of a system has entropic consequences. It is therefore impossible to dissociate the mind's information from the body's entropy. Knowledge of that state of the system without an energetically significant measurement would lead to a violation of the second law of thermodynamics.

To once and for all solve the problem of dualism, I propose then to perform an experiment by confining a subject to an isolation room with a carefully monitored temperature wherein the subject has to perform hard maths problems. The hypothesis for dualism is to measure a violation of the second law of thermodynamics. To do this it is necessary to calculate the change in entropy (ΔS) of the isolation room. The hypothesis holds if there is such a violation, that is ΔS < 0. If there is no such violation, that is ΔS ≥ 0, the hypothesis is false.
For the null hypothesis, it is necessary to repeat the experiment with the subject under general anaesthesia. This person won't be doing any hard maths problems. The null hypothesis is no violation of the second law of thermodynamics.
I will work out the details tonight.

Thermodynamic reality, whatever that may be apart from the mental representations of physical models arising in my mind, does not seem to be compelling an upvote at this time! But some mysterious underlying thermodynamic process just might drive my conscious mind to that decision! Thank you for the link to the paper it does appear to be on point.

Essentially you are talking about measuring the heat emitted by a brain when doing different types of tasks. This has been done. It turns out the brain needs a steady flow of energy, pretty much irrespective of what it does. See: https://www.brainfacts.org/brain-anatomy-and-function/anatomy/2019/how-much-energy-does-the-brain-use-020119

@Olivier5 The point is that mental causation has to increase information in the physical brain by inducing a pattern of firing neurons where there was no pattern before without the use of free energy (ΔG). This because it is not physically causal and should therefore not generate heat. How could it? Like I said I am working out the details.  Don't stand in the way of my Nobel Prize!

You mean, you want to test the idea that mental causation is not causal???

@Olivier5 Either that or breaking the second law of thermodynamics. You choose.

Non-causal causation breaks the laws of logic, though. There must be something wrong with your idea.

@Olivier5 I was construing a thought experiment. It shows that proving dualism right would mean to break the second law of thermodynamics which is, of course, unheard of. It was a bit of a facetious way of trying to argue that dualism is incoherent. The article is genuine though.

Seriously, and as explained, there's a number of experiments about the thermodynamics of the brain, and showing similarly levels of energy consumption whether one stares into the void or works on a math problem. This pleads for the brain building a platform for thoughts. The platform consumes as much energy, whether you use it or not. Similarly, once you switch on a computer, its energy consumption will remain stable, whether you work on it or not.

@Olivier5 except that's not how computer work, at least not any more.  when the CPU is not processing instructions it goes into an idle state which reduces power consumption. when i'm not chatting with Llama 3, the GPU stops using 90W of power.  for simple tasks like word processing it may be a close approximation simply because these tasks often don't use much processing power.

@Andy That's a technicality, though.

The definition of mind-body dualism quoted from Britannica in the OP’s  post does not help much. The definition operates with mind and body as two substances.

IMO, from start on it is a false approach to consider “mind” as a
substance. Instead, mind is a process, a concept to capture
dynamics. While substance is a concept to capture static objects and properties.
One can relate body and
brain. The latter being a component of the body. But to relate body
to mind, the activity of the brain, is a category error.

The splitting “mind-body” has a long tradition. But it is not
suitable as a basis to investigate the anthropology of a human
person.
When considering the person as a whole one can distiguish
the structure of its components, on one hand. And the operation of
its components, on the other hand.  The operation of the brain
component are the mental processes, vulgo “mind”.


To build an anthropology on this basis - considering mind as the information processing of the brain - seems more promising than the Cartesion dualism of a former time for an interdiciplinary enterprise with the participation of neuroscience .

I quoted a second source complementing the first source. I don't know if it helps.

@user80226 Please decide first which of the two sources you take as the basis of your post. - Alternatively, you can ask a separate question about an operationable definition of mind and body which allows to check correponding statements.

My question clearly and explicitly asks Are there versions of mind-body dualism that are empirically testable?, so I hope it's quite evident that my question is not tied to a specific version. I'm seeking answers from people who are knowledgeable enough in the topic to be able to point to different versions of mind-body dualism. If you were not aware of any definitions of mind-body dualism before I asked the question, probably you are not the best candidate to answer it (with all due respect).

@user80226 Then it possibly helps to study first https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/dualism/

I think this one is better: https://iep.utm.edu/dualism-and-mind/

But none of them says anything about falsifiability, which is the main focus of my question.

@user80226 How far did you come with your own study of their falsifiability, which open question remains?

Not very far, it's hard to find papers on the scientific testability of mind-body dualism.

Saying mind is process not substance already pre-decides the negation of mind-body dualism as the case and then proceeds to a circular 'proof'. For analogy, imagine a computer scientist who says computing/information is not a thing; there is only electronic engineering

@Rushi I expanded the last sentence of my answer.

I think it is reasonable to assume that when someone speaks of the mind-body problem, they are well aware that this phrase is a term of art standing for something like 'the question of whether the minds are entirely the consequence of physical bodies doing purely physical things'... Similarly, when Searle asked 'Is the Brain a Digital Computer?' I trust we can assume he did not think anyone was unsure about the answer to that question when taken literally.

OP: "Is mind-body dualism falsifiable?"
Descartes established the cogito and existence in "cogito ergo sum", and then apparently leapt to the conclusion of dualism without justification.

Descartes argues that mind and body are really distinct in two places
in the Sixth Meditation. The first argument is that he has a clear
and distinct understanding of the mind as a thinking, non-extended
thing and of the body as an extended, non-thinking thing. . . . that
these perceptions are clear and distinct indicates that the mind
cannot help but believe them true, . . . Therefore, the mind can
exist without the body and vice versa. IEP

In this view, since there is no hypothesis dualism is not falsifiable.
Heidegger refers to the dualism's distinction as "baseless" . . .

If, in the ontology of Dasein, we 'take our departure'
from a worldless "I" in order to provide this "I" with an Object and
an ontologically baseless relation to that Object, then we have
'presupposed' not too much, but too little. B&T
315-6

and says that Dasein's basic state is Being-in-the-world. In the world with discoverable things.

The compound expression 'Being-in-the-world' indicates in the very way
we have coined it, that it stands for a unitary phenomenon. This
primary datum must be seen as a whole. B&T
53

In this manner dualism is rendered incoherent.

No, mind-body dualism is not falsifiable by physical experimentation, because physical models are recursive on the experience of conscious mind. The distinction between body and mind arises in the conscious mind. The experiments depend on the recognition of such distinction. Idealism is more coherent than physicalism because both theories arise in the conscious mind.
SEP Articles - Epiphenomenalism, Dualism, Monism, Idealism, Physicalism
https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/epiphenomenalism/

Many philosophers recognize a distinction between two kinds of mental events. (A) The first goes by many names, e.g., phenomenal experiences, occurrences of qualitative consciousness, the what-it-is-like of experience, qualia. Pains, afterimages, and tastes can serve as examples. (B) Mental events of the second kind are occurrent propositional attitudes, e.g., (occurrent) beliefs and desires.

https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/dualism/

The mind-body problem is the problem: what is the relationship between mind and body? Or alternatively: what is the relationship between mental properties and physical properties?


Humans have (or seem to have) both physical properties and mental properties. People have (or seem to have)the sort of properties attributed in the physical sciences. These physical properties include size, weight, shape, colour, motion through space and time, etc. But they also have (or seem to have) mental properties, which we do not attribute to typical physical objects These properties involve consciousness (including perceptual experience, emotional experience, and much else), intentionality (including beliefs, desires, and much else), and they are possessed by a subject or a self.

https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/monism/

Substance monism targets concrete objects and counts by highest types. This is the doctrine that all concrete objects fall under one highest type (perhaps material, or mental, or some neutral underlying type: here the way divides). This topic is covered elsewhere in the encyclopedia (Robinson 2011).

https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/idealism/

Within modern philosophy there are sometimes taken to be two fundamental conceptions of idealism:

something mental (the mind, spirit, reason, will) is the ultimate foundation of all reality, or even exhaustive of reality, and
although the existence of something independent of the mind is conceded, everything that we can know about this mind-independent “reality” is held to be so permeated by the creative, formative, or constructive activities of the mind (of some kind or other) that all claims to knowledge must be considered, in some sense, to be a form of self-knowledge.



Idealism in sense (1) has been called “metaphysical” or “ontological idealism”, while idealism in sense (2) has been called “formal” or “epistemological idealism”.

https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/physicalism/

Physicalism is, in slogan form, the thesis that everything is physical. The thesis is usually intended as a metaphysical thesis, parallel to the thesis attributed to the ancient Greek philosopher Thales, that everything is water, or the idealism of the 18th Century philosopher Berkeley, that everything is mental. The general idea is that the nature of the actual world (i.e. the universe and everything in it) conforms to a certain condition, the condition of being physical. Of course, physicalists don’t deny that the world might contain many items that at first glance don’t seem physical — items of a biological, or psychological, or moral, or social, or mathematical nature. But they insist nevertheless that at the end of the day such items are physical, or at least bear an important relation to the physical.

Limits of Conceptual Knowledge
Concepts are distinctions that arise in the conscious mind.
Mental items:

qualia
desires
concepts

Qualia may arise in the mind independent of concepts. But to discuss qualia one must form, recognize, and evoke concepts in the mind of self and others. Desires are somewhat distinct from qualia or concepts. But desires have no aim or goal that can be specified independent of qualia or concepts. Beliefs fit under the experience of concepts. Models of the physical world arise as maps, relations, or compound concepts in the mind.
The article on physicalism exposes the problem: conceptual knowledge arises in the mind. Like many items of conceptual knowledge the concept(s) called physicalism are fuzzy, indistinct, and uncertain. The effort to reduce the mind to a physical model fails because physical models are recursive on the conceptual knowledge of the mind.

What do you mean by "recursive"? I'm familiar with the concept of recursion in mathematics and computer science, so I'm having a hard time trying to understand what you mean by "recursive" here. Can you please provide examples of recursion in this context to clarify the meaning?

@user80226 My understanding of recursion in computer science is when a function calls itself. The effort to falsify mind-body dualism calls upon the conceptual knowledge of the mind to recognize the distinctions and outcomes of experiments. There is no way to isolate the concepts of physical models from conceptual knowledge in the mind.

Right, for a lever to move anything, you need something that is not the lever or the thing you are trying to move. We need to find the real world already.

@ScottRowe. Zen Center of Los Angeles https://zcla.org/articles-joshuswashyourbowl/. Case: A monk asked Joshu in all earnestness, “I have just entered this monastery. I beg you, Master, teach me.” Joshu asked, “Have you eaten your rice gruel?” The monk answered, “Yes, I have.”Joshu said, “Wash your bowl.”At that moment, the monk was enlightened. Mummon’s Commentary: Joshu opened his mouth and showed his gallbladder, and revealed his heart and liver. If this monk, hearing it, failed to grasp the Truth, he would mistake a bell for a pot. My comment: Reality rings like empty bell not a full pot.
